# Reason for variation in ping time to AWS Global Accelerator

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, ping

While testing AWS global accelerator, I see variation in the ping to global accelerator address.

[screen shot of ping time to Global Accelerator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caz84.png)

In the attached image it can be seen that the ping time ranges from 5.64 ms to 53.5 ms. FWIW I am testing from Windows environment.

I am testing from Mumbai and trying to connect to Global Accelerator generated URL.

What explains this variation in the ping time.

Comment: For someone to help you out, they could benefit with a little more information. Ex, what environment are you currently in? I.e wireless or wired, where is your aws instance located (region) in relation to you ? All such things could help others, help you. 

Oh and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for informing.  I have updated my question to add more details.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/37645/does-a-high-variation-in-ping-response-times-indicate-a-potential-network-issue

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, which is a low priority for routers. Routers are designed to route as fast as possible, and generating ICMP messages is a low priority. Basically, a router gets around to responding to ping (generating an ICMP reply) when it has time. If it gets busy routing, the ping response could be slowed. ICMP (ping) in no way reflects the performance of other protocols (TCP, UDP, etc.) on the network.